# "Unlock" ECS Iris8 MCP61PM-HM (NETTLE1) v5.26 Motherboard

Tags: windows-7

So I have a Compaq Presario SR5510F.
Athlon 64 X2 (B) 5000+ 2.6 GHz (65W)

All the specs can be found here...
http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&docname=c01463074

The only thing I have done/added to my computer is an MSI Radeon HD4350 Graphics Card.

I'm VERY new to overclocking, in fact, I've never overclocked a computer before but since I cant afford an X4 chip & new motherboard I figured I'd try to bring my 2.6MHz to maybe 2.9MHz or even 2.8MHz.  Anything for a little extra power.  (I'm a gamer without a gaming machine)

So here's the issue: after much research I have found that my OEM motherboard is "locked" so that people such as myself cant go into the BIOS & default on the manufacturers warranty.  As much as I appreciate the hand holding I prefer to be left to my own devices.

After hours & hours of link after link I have found is that 99.99% say it is impossible to accomplish, than 0.01% say that they have "unlocked" this exact motherboard (or NETTLE2) yet are not that eager to divulge their techniques.

Now, I ask myself, if they locked this motherboard did they actually throw away the key or can this lock be picked?

Now, I'm asking whomever, is it possible to pick this lock? if so how? if not why?  I'm not a total "noob" (I hate that word BTW) when it comes to computers so please don't give me some random "It cant be done" answer.  I'm looking for precise explanation of the steps taken to permanently lock/unlock a motherboard.

Windows 7 32-bit Ultimate if it matters.

*"I'll never truly be happy until I have ALL the answers" ~ myself*

[image]

Comment: This demonstrates one of the disadvantages of buying OEM systems: the manufacturer can do all kinds of annoying things, including branding the O/S and crippling the system.  They have a strong motivation to prevent people from tinkering, since they provide both warranty and support for the computer.  My hunch is that they disabled the overclocking features of the chipset in the BIOS.  If I'm right, getting around this limitation would involve finding compatible, unrestricted BIOS firmware and burning a new BIOS chip.

Answer (score 1):

I have an HP board that looks exactly like yours (ECS Nettle2-gl8e) in fact you have the wrong board pictured

Here is the link to your board I believe:

http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&docname=c01237538

only difference is yours only has 2 ram slots

flash it with ECS Geforce6100SM-M (V1.0/1.0A ) motherboard firmware.  It's the same hardware on that board and I did it with mine and worked fine other than I had to reactivate windows vista due to the bios change.

Totaly way more options to set in bios though.  Still ran rock solid after the flash too.

Make sure that right after you flash though that you clear the bios settings by either removing coin battery from board with power removed for 30 seconds then replace or use the clear cmos jumper on the board to do it.

If you don't clear bios settings after flashing ecs firmware the computer will not boot untill you do.

Oh and by the way, if you look on the hp site this board is made by ECS.

Link to the ECS site for the Geforce6100sm-m board: http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?DetailID=685&CategoryID=1&MenuID=21&LanID=9

You should be able to get the bios from the downloads section. Just make sure it's for the v1.0/1.0a board.